# How to connect 2 different hosts in mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a service in ruby and I trying to connect with two different hosts with two different databases

I'm trying something like this

mongoid.yml

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: cpeTracking
      hosts:
       - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
       - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
       - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
      options:
        user: my_user
        password: my_password
        auth_source: admin
        ssl: true
      database: testDb
        hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

And my model

```
class Movies
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  store_in database: "testDb"

  field :name, type: String
  field :year, type: Integer
  field :director, type: String
end
```

When I run the service, only connect with the first host. 
I also tried this solution 
[Connecting to two databases Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400458/connecting-to-two-databases-mongoid) but didn't work

Comment: In your paste, all the hosts are the same though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
First I have to create a new client at same level of default, I called it "secondary" with the info of database and host.

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: my_db
      hosts:
        - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
        - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
        - development-shard.mongodb.net:27017
      options:
        user: my_user
        password: my_pass
        auth_source: admin
        ssl: true
    secondary:
      database: testDb
      hosts:
       - localhost:27017
```

Second. In the model I had to add the collection, the database and the client that will use

```
class Movies
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  store_in collection: "movies", database: "testDb", client: "secondary"

  field :name, type: String
  field :year, type: Integer
  field :director, type: String
end
```